# Sublime Text 2 Keyboard shortcut to open file in Chrome/firefox in windows

Tags: google-chrome, build, sublimetext, shortcut

I followed the instruction for windows 7 to setup chrome. No luck!

```
{
 "cmd":["C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application", "$C:\Users\gmu\Desktop\June_15_2012"]
}
```

after entering the file location/path under what format should I have to save. I am a noobie. sorry to ask this question. Anything helps!

If I press f7 getting the following message
Error trying to parse build system: Invalid escape in C:\Users\gmu\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text2\Packages\User\Chrome.sublime-build:2:9

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. preferences > key bindings-user should look like this in windows:

   ```
   [
   // *RIGHT* { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "open_browser" },
   // *WRONG* { "keys": ["f12"], "ctrl": "open_browser" }, 

   { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "open_browser" },
   { "keys": ["ctrl+e"], "command": "HtmlDialect" },
   { "keys": ["/"], "command": "close_tag_on_slash" }
   ]
   ```
2. look in your packages folder for a folder called 'openbrow' then open the openbrow.py file in sublime

find the icon for the browser you want to use and goto it's properties to copy the path to it's location on your computer

then in the openbrow file your gonna paste that path where it should go. 
for instance `([r'C:\path to your browser', '-new-tab', self.view.file_name()])`

here's what my openbrow.py file looks like:

```
    import sublime, sublime_plugin
    import subprocess

    class OpenBrowserCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,edit):
    subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files 
    (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe','-new-tab', self.view.file_name()])
```

hope this helps! KCCO

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Sublime View In Browser](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser)
extension that, quote:

> *View In Browser is a Sublime Text 2 plugin that will open whatever is in your current view/tab.*

Installation in using instructions in tne `README.md` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and found this post ! My problem was fixed by just typing this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"]
}
```

Notice that double `\\` solved my problem ..

And then I saved it as Chrome.sublime-build on:

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows this code is working.
Go to Tools > Build System > New Build System
Then put the code with your browser file path.

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "$file"]
}
```

Please use double '\\' for '\'.
Hope it will work.