# sublime text 3 not showing files in browser

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to view files from sublime text in browser in windows 8.1 32 bit.I creted a new build system under Tools/Build System.I put this code in there

```
{
"cmd":["C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "$file"]
}
```

I saved this file as **Chrome.sublime-build** in the packages/user folder.
i checked chrome in tools/build sysytem.Then if i trying to view files in browser by pressing **CTRL+B** nothing happens.What is the problem?

Comment: try using double slashes as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27659250/4473405)

Comment: Thank you very much , it works now.